# What is the difference between `sort(str.begin(), str.end())` and `sort(std::begin(str), std::end(str))` in C++? Or are these same, and if so, why?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, c++14

What is the difference between using `sort(str.begin(), str.end())` and using `sort(std::begin(str), std::end(str))` in C++?

Both of these functions gave the same result as the sorted string but is there any difference between the two, and what is the reason for having both?

Comment: `std::begin()` and `std::end()` were introduced in C++11.   The `begin()` and `end()` members of all standard containers have existed since (at least) C++98.   Functionally, for standard containers, `std::begin()` and `std::end()` call the corresponding member functions for the object passed to them (which, with a suitably optimising compiler doing inlining, means they are largely equivalent).  There are also overloads of `std::begin()` and `std::end()` for raw arrays - which don't have member functions.

Answer (score 12):

Same thing, but if you write `begin(str)` it also works with things like arrays. If str was an array then `str.begin()` wouldn't work because an array isn't a class. Therefore some people like to make a habit of writing `begin(str)`.

Comment: I like this answer. The other answer is incomplete.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, `begin(str)` wouldn't work for (built-in) arrays. You still need `std::begin(str)`.

Answer (score 7):

From the c++ reference of [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin), for a non-array:

> 1. Returns exactly c.begin(), which is typically an iterator to the
>    beginning of the sequence represented by c. If C is a standard
>    Container, this returns C::iterator when c is not const-qualified, and
>    C::const_iterator otherwise.

Hence, using `str.begin()` or `std::begin(str)` for a `std::string` str is exactly the same.

Comment: That doesn't explain the why in the question